# How to duplicate Django models with OneToOneField relations

Tags: python, django

Start with the following models using django==3.2.12:

```
from django.db import models


class Root(models.Model):
  pass

class Leaf(models.Model):
  root = models.OneToOneField(Root, related_name='leaf_data', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Run the following in the shell:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Root, Leaf
>>> root = Root()
>>> root.save()
>>> leaf = Leaf(root=root)
>>> leaf.save()
>>> root
<Root: Root object (1)>
>>> leaf
<Leaf: Leaf object (1)>
>>> new_root = Root()
>>> new_root.save()
>>> new_root
<Root: Root object (2)>
>>> root.leaf_data
<Leaf: Leaf object (1)>
>>> leaf = root.leaf_data
>>> leaf.pk = None
>>> leaf.root = new_root
>>> leaf.save()
>>> leaf.root
<Root: Root object (2)>
>>> root.leaf_data
<Leaf: Leaf object (2)>
```

Why does the original `root.leaf_data` reference change? I would expect that by setting `leaf.pk = None` and `leaf.root = new_root` that the original root/leaf structure would remain intact. I'm trying to create a full duplicate from the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't change on db. If you do `root.refresh_from_db()` `root.leaf_data` should be <Leaf: Leaf object (1)>.

What happened is you used `root.leaf_data` object to create another Leaf. After `save` django hydrated this `Leaf` instance with data of newly created leaf - <Leaf: Leaf object (2)>. But `root` still points at this object!

If you created new `Leaf` and not reused the instance the problem wouldn't occur :D